# Merging dataframes with occasionally missing files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am merging xml domains through an API (dm and dd below). However, sometimes a domain may not be present if there is no data in it. For example, it's not uncommon for the DD domain to not be present.

I've added code to tell it how to deal with missing data, but not a whole missing domain.

```
relevant_dm_cols = ['SUBJID', 'USUBJID', 'BRTHDTC', 'SEX', 'RACE', 'ETHNIC']
relevant_dd_cols = ['USUBJID', 'DDDTC']

datax = (dm
                        .merge(dd, on=['USUBJID'], sort='false')
                        .sort_values(['SUBJID']))

        dmreport = pd.DataFrame({
                'Participant': datax.SUBJID,
                'Date of Death': datax.DDDTC,
                'Year of Birth': datax.year,
                'Sex': datax.SEX,
                'Race': datax.RACE,
                'Ethnicity': datax.ETHNIC

        })

        dmreport.replace(to_replace=[None], value=np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Here's an example of an error: 
 dd = self.data['DD'].loc[:,relevant_dd_cols]
KeyError: 'DD'.
    What code can I add which will still pull all the other data, but ignore the DD merge and DDDTC column if if there is no DD domain present at any given time?

Comment: you could try `datax.get('DDDTC')` rather than `datax.DDDTC`.

Comment: I tried this, didn't work. I updated the error that I'm now getting. The domain missing seems to be the problem, not the variable that comes from it.

Comment: Could you share a consistent example of the code that generates this error? Your code as it stands, just generates a NameError, because you define neither dm nor dd.